# How to define descending sort order (in XAML) for DataGrid in SL/WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

In order to define column sorting the SortMemberPath can be used. But how can I define that this column shall be sorted descending?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help but you may want to look at the [CollectionViewSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(VS.95).aspx). There is a [SortDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions(VS.95).aspx) property where the sort order can be set. Take a look at [this post](http://blog.boschin.it/articles/Improving-Silverlight-2.0-databinding-with-a-CollectionViewSource-control.aspx) for some sample code.